# Using a specific LCD with an arduino

Tags: arduino, lcd

I have the following [lcd (DisplayTech 128x64 COG STN Y/G)](http://za.rs-online.com/web/p/products/564-400/) unfortunately after reading the data sheet I still have no idea how to hook this up with an arduino. Could someone either assist in explain how this needs to be hooked up and how you would interface with it once connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses a ST7565R controller from Sitronix.

Use the [controller datasheet](http://www.gpegint.com/files/library/files/supportpdf/ST7565R_V17_960601.pdf).

On pages 38/39 you can find reference examples for the voltage generator connections an on page 66 you find the MCU connection examples.

Comment: Dude you rock, after much searching i finally came across an older version of that doc as well. Thanks for pointing out specifically which pages to look at , i was initially confused about the CAP* connection but i see they are not used

Comment: Also do you know if I can use this with an arduino without the need to 4050 level shifter chip

Comment: @RC1140 No. The datasheet states that the maximum input voltage is VDD (3.3V) (page 57) .

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation , even though I read that in the data sheet I wasnt 100% sure.